# .NET file downloading library

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any library with functions for downloading files from the internet? I need to download some files using threads to increase speed.

Comment: You mean something more than the `WebClient` and `WebRequest` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WebClient](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708092857/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/09/14/.net-memory-management-ndash-resources.aspx) and background worker, threadpool or threads to do this fairly easily.

This question has also been posted on here in a few different forms as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple threads to download won't, in many cases, increase throughput/speed- in fact, it will frequently have the opposite effect. Your pipe is only so large, so unless the other end is the limiting factor and you have multiple endpoints to download from, there's not a lot of benefit for the complexity.

Comment: I just now came back here to say that. The OP seems to be assuming that more threads will be better.

Comment: I know that opening more threads wont give me more speed than the cap my ISP has put on me, I need the threads because the site where I download the files from limits the bandwidth per connection, and the limit is less than the bandwidth of my connection, so if I open a new connection on separate threads I should get more speed.